# Pivot Function adding more rows than expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I couldn't think of a better title, if someone can think of a better one, I am up for suggestions.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Source    TableName     Detail     active_status     RowCount
a          table_one     stuff      active               500
b          table_two     stuff_2    active               750
c          table_three   stuff_3    inactive            1000
d          table_four    stuff_4    active               200
e          table_five    stuff_5    inactive             200
```

When I run this query:

```
select [a], [b], [c], [d], [e]
from (select [source], [rowcount] from ParentStaged) as src_tbl
pivot
(
    avg([rowcount])
    for source in ([a], [b], [c], [d], [e])
) as pivot_tbl;
```

I get this result:

```
  a       b        c      d       e
500     750     1000    200     200
```

When I run this query:

```
select [a], [b], [c], [d], [e]
from (select [source], [TableName], [rowcount] from ParentStaged) as src_tbl
pivot
(
    avg([rowcount])
    for source in ([a], [b], [c], [d], [e])
) as pivot_tbl;
```

I produce this result:

```
   a        b        c       d       e
 500     null     null    null    null
null      750     null    null    null
null     null     1000    null    null
null     null     null     200    null
null     null     null    null     200
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out why.

It has nothing to do with the quantity of columns I'm adding in the from clause, it has to do with what I am adding exactly.

The aggregation performs a calculation based on what I tell it to aggregate on listed in my from clause. The group by is performed on what I am not using in the aggregation.

If I list columns that are not common between the other groups, that is what causes the null values to appear.

If I list columns that are common, null values will not appear.

Comment: Correct. In your second query, PIVOT automatically groups the records by `TableName`, just because it's there.